# Jquery Radio Button Submit Form

Tags: php, jquery, serialization, radio-button, submit

I have multiple forms on one page all are like this: The ID value changes but the options can be similar.

```
<form class="test"><td>4000</td>
<td align='center'><input type='radio' name='radio' value='car' checked></td>
<td align='center'><input type='radio' name='radio' value='boat' ></td>
<td align='center'><input type='radio' name='radio' value='Plane' ></td>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='4000'/>
<input type='hidden' name='location' value='local'/>
<div class="form" style="display: none;">
</div></form>
```

Using JQuery I'm trying to submit this when any of the 3 radio buttons are selected.

```
<script>
$("input[name='radio']").click(function() {
    var CurrectForm=$(this).parents('.test:first');
    $.post(
        'do.php',
        CurrectForm.serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            CurrectForm.find('#form').html( response );
               show( response );
        }
    );
} );
</script>
```

I've used similar to the above with checkboxes and dropdown lists, which have worked fine. But this doesn't seem to submit the values to the do.php page. The values that are submitted are show in the div form. Doing a `var_dump($_POST);`  results in an empty array.

Can someone point me in the right direction ?
Thanks

Changing the form ti this seems to work ?

```
<td><form class="test">
<input type='radio' name='radio' value='car' checked>
<input type='radio' name='radio' value='boat' >
<input type='radio' name='radio' value='Plane' >
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='4000'/>
<input type='hidden' name='location' value='local'/>
<div class="form" style="display: none;">
</div></form></td>
```

Why does changing the  cause it to work ?

Jfiddle with working example :) http://jsfiddle.net/QvpH5/

Comment: Have you tried to `console.dir(CurrectForm)` to see if you are selecting it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there are multiple forms on your page with the class `test`. What is happening, is when you use `parents()`, you don't realize **it first finds all of the ancestors**, and **then searches for** `.test:first`. This will return the very first form's values, regardless of which form is clicked.

Look at this jsFiddle to see the fix (change .parents to .parent): http://jsfiddle.net/SDzzr/

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the issue is partly due to the form layout over multiple <TD>'s.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Were you able to see the code in jsFiddle that I provided? It seemed to fix the issue

Comment: Thanks it does work.. until you add a table to the layout.. The the array is empty. Any way to by pass that ?

Comment: Chances are you are just not traversing up the DOM enough for your specific use case. Just chain more .parent() functions together, to get the specific level. Use console.dir() to print out the form values, to tell when you got to the right level

Comment: Thanks, I've partially got it working. But it only ever selects the values from the first form, the page could have 10 - 60 forms..
this is what I have http://jsfiddle.net/QvpH5/

Comment: Your error lies with your table. You have your form and div tags mixed in with your table, but outside of your `<td>` tags. You'll need to fix that before you can figure anything out